# ASP.Net OData fails with SSL Termination in LB

Tags: asp.net, https, odata, owin, load-balancing

I have an issue using HTTPS to access an ASP.NET OData endpoint. The ASP.NET site is hosted via OWIN. I am using the NuGet package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData for the OData (v3) part. The SSL termination takes place outside of the server in a separate load balancer.

Accessing the OData endpoints with a REST-client (e.g. Postman) works fine: https://api.my-domain.com/odata/v3

But when I use an OData-client (e.g. Excel or PowerBI), the access fails with the generic message, that the host forcibly closed the connection.

Further I found that when I access the endpoint https://api.my-domain.com/odata/v3 via Postman, I receive some XML metadata, which refers to the normal **http** endpoint (see below snippet), which is blocked by the LB.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service xml:base="http://api.my-domain.com/odata/v3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<workspace>
   ...
```

Further I sniffed the traffic from Excel/PowerBI with Wireshark and found that the clients are using the normal **http** endpoint (as shown in above metadata) after the initial request with **https**. I am not familiar with the OData protocol details, but I guess the clients are determining the address by the metadata.

For validation I unblocked port 80 in the LB and voila, Excel/PowerBI can successfully connect, regardless if I use **http** or **https** for the initial request.

But how to solve this issue (I don't want to allow traffic on **http**). Is it possible to instruct the ASP.NET OData middleware to generate metadata with **https** URIs?